# How to create custom async event in js?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I develop an app in Javascript where I have to create 2 custom async events.

My function for dispatching these events is:

```js
fireTwoEvents: function() {
  console.log('first event dispatching');
  element.dispatchEvent(event1); // fire function1

  console.log('second event dispatching');
  element.dispatchEvent(event2); // fire function2

}
```

These 2 events (and functions) are independent and I want to fire both events asynchronously.

But second event is firing after `function1()` is done.

How to fix it?

Comment: Fix what? `dispatchEvent` is synchronous.

Comment: How to do it async?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create 2 promises and then use `Promise.all()` to simultaneously fire 2 events (asynchronously).

```js
fireTwoEvents: function() {
  ...
  ... some code ...
  ...
  
  const promise1 = new Promise(() => {
    console.log('first event dispatching);
    element.dispatchEvent(event1);
  });
  
  const promise2 = new Promise(() => {
    console.log('second event dispatching);
    element.dispatchEvent(event2);
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);

}
```